# Python module distribution installs executable to path

Tags: python, pypi

In the past I saw Python module distributions on PyPI which installed an executable to the path when you installed them with `pip`, unfortunately I can't find one like this anymore.

I wonder how this is possible. Would you do this in your `setup.py`? Can you get this to work for multiple platforms?

A link to a module doing this would be very helpful as well.

**I'm NOT talking about installing python modules to the python path but installing *executables to the system path*!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

> ### The `scripts` Keyword Argument
>
> The first approach is to write your
>   script in a separate file, such as you might write a shell script.:
>
> ```
> funniest/
>      funniest/
>          __init__.py
>          ...
>      setup.py
>      bin/
>          funniest-joke
> ```
>
> ... The funniest-joke script just looks like this:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env python
>
> import funniest print funniest.joke()
> ```
>
> Then we can declare the script
>   in `setup()` like this:
>
> ```
> setup(
>     ...
>     scripts=['bin/funniest-joke'],
>     ... )
> ```
>
> When we install the package, `setuptools` will copy the script to our `PATH` and make it available for general use.